# Mock a Property Getter Throw an Exception Using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, moq

I would like to mock a property that I found using reflection to throw an exception when someone tries to Get from it. The problem is that I do not know the type of `ID`. Below is an example of what I have tried:

```
internal static T CreateObjectWithExceptioningIDProperty<T>() where T : class
{
  Type type = typeof(T);
  var moq = new Mock<T>();
  var lambdaParameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
  PropertyInfo idProperty = type.GetProperties().First(pi => pi.Name.Equals("ID"));
  var lambdaBody = Expression.Property(lambdaParameter, idProperty);
  dynamic func = Expression.Lambda(lambdaBody, lambdaParameter);
  moq.Setup(func).Throws(new Exception()); // get RuntimeBinderException
  return moq.Object;
}
```

Currently, I get a `RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Throws'`. What am I doing wrong?

This is similar to [Moq and reflection, passing dynamically generated expression tree / lambda to moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334184/moq-and-reflection-passing-dynamically-generated-expression-tree-lambda-to-mo) and [Create an Expression<Func<,>> using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712726/create-an-expressionfunc-using-reflection).

Comment: Your `RuntimeBinderException` is because you can't use extension methods on `dynamic` types (since `func` is `dynamic`, `moq.Setup(func)` is too). Maybe cast it to an appropriate type or don't use the extension method syntax?

Comment: Is this for unit testing?  If so, its got code smells.

Comment: Yes it is for unit testing, but it is a long story (legacy code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast the result of `Setup` to `IThrows`, it works. I'm not sure why it fails how you have it; maybe because the runtime type of `moq.Setup(func)` is not normally visible (it's `internal` to `Moq`).

```
((IThrows)moq.Setup(func)).Throws(new Exception());
```

Comment: I bet it is because the `Setup()` is an extension method (like you commented above).

Comment: @MageWind actually, I don't think either `Setup` or `Throws` is an extension method. When I wrote the comment, I guessed that `Throws` was, but I was wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
moq.Setup( x => x.Id).Throws(new Exception());
```

?

Comment: You might consider adding more to your answer, particularly since you don't seem sure it's correct.

Comment: you don't seem that certain

Comment: yea that would work, but I forgot to mention that I will not know the name of the property at compile time.